# cant access data return{} varibles in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

```js
function HeaderreRender() { 
  HeaderRender = false;
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    HeaderRender = true;
  });
};

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    HeaderItem,
  },
  data: function() { 
    return {
      HeaderRender: true,
    };
  }
}
```

this is the code now I want to use `v-if="HeaderRender"` to re-render the `headerItem`
but when I call function `HeaderreRender()`
it is replying to me
`Uncaught ReferenceError: HeaderRender is not defined`
on the function

any suggestions? on why this happens?

Comment: since you're using old-school "options API", then use old school `this.HeaderRender = true;` - you actually seem to be mixing options and composition API patterns - choose 1 and stick to it, and things will start to work

Comment: @Bravo I got replied with this when added this. to HeaderRender ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'HeaderRender')```

Comment: that's because you're mixing options and composition API patterns - you can't do that in the one component - choose 1 and stick to it (you can use options API in some components and composition in another if you want though - just not mixed in one component)

Answer (score 3):

Try to place the `HeadereRender()` function within the **methods** object of the component and also, it's `this.HeaderRender=true`

In simple terms, this method does not know about the `HeaderRender` variable, thus it is not defined in the scope of the function, written that way

Comment: the main issue is, OP is mixing options API with composition API and doing both wrong